# Code-first changing the name of bridge entity table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

Is there a way to control the name of the table that the bridge entity creates? Right now if I run this:

```
public class Foo
{
    public Int32 FooId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
}

public class Bar
{
    public Int32 BarId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Foo> Foos { get; set; }
}
```

The resulting bridge table is named BarFoo, any way to make it FooBar instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can customize the table name by mapping as follows.

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{    
     protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
     {
         modelBuilder.Entity<Foo>()
           .HasMany(e => e.Bars)
           .WithMany(s => s.Foos)
           .Map(l =>
             {
                l.ToTable("FooBar");
                l.MapLeftKey("FooId");
                l.MapRightKey("BarId");
             }
           );
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not work as I was hoping, at least in EF 6 it doesn't.  My Up migration calls it FooBar as expected, my Down migration calls it FooBar as expected.  For all intensive purposes you would think that the table is actually called FooBar since I can reference it as such in the code.  However, looking in SQL Management Studio, I can see that the physical table is "still" named BooFar instead.  Entity is just making some mapping for me in the code, not actually naming the actual table itself.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `EntityTypeConfiguration` and the fluent config api. There is a HasMany() method in there which should do what you want.

Comment: oh I was really trying to avoid fluent api... Hoping there is some way to decorate something....

Comment: okay. i'm the other way around, i hate decorating my code with loads of attributes, it looks messy IMO. each to their own ;)